# Integral of $f(x,y) = 1$ for $y>x$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Tags: riemann-integration, multiple-integral

I'm trying to figure out the integral of

$$f(x,y): ([0,1] \times [0,1])  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ for } y>x,\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Graphically this seems like it should be $\frac{1}{2}$.
 However, I cannot see how the upper and lower Riemann integrals give this.

Comment: Is it $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^1\int_0^y 1 \, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ ?